# Рекурсивный обход дерева

Tags: java

У меня есть вот такое вот дерево
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как я могу обойти всех детей рекурсивно если каждый узел может иметь много детей?

Comment: Обход в глубину и обход в ширину вам в помошь. Это два самых простых вида обхода графа, а дерево как раз является частным видом графа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим, ваше дерево описывается такой структурой:

```
class Node {
   String name; //имя
   Node[] nodes; //потомки
}
```

Рекурсивный метод обхода будет такой:

```
void routeTree(Node startNode) {
    System.out.println("Node="+startNode.name);
    for(Node node : startNode.nodes)
        routeTree(node);
}
```

Comment: Вообще само дерево заполняется из базы данных немного сложным методом

Comment: Вы не спрашивали о заполнении дерева, а задавали вопрос по рекурсивному обходу дерева :) Впрочем, какая разница как дерево заполняется?